# Dynamic task generation in an Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I want to use Airflow to generate client reports, I would like to have one DAG that loops through all clients and launches a task to generate their report. The list of clients is gathered by the first task in the DAG and cannot be hardcoded in.

Basically I have a task that uses a database hook in a python operator to generate a list. Then for each item in the list I would like to execute a task using a python operator with that item being passed as an argument to the python function. Is there a certain pattern I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger_dag concept

Let the task that uses a database hook in a python operator to generate a list" be the task in the **controller dag** and pass the each item in list to the **trigger_dag** in the params section.

You will find reference in the examples folder in your airflow installation

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @priyank but I do not understand yet. The `python_callable` in the `TriggerDagRunOperator` can read the params but can only return a single dag object to create a dag run. I need to execute the `TriggerDagRunOperator` N times with different params each time. Where does the fanning out of tasks (or DagRuns) take place?